# VBA for Summing a Filtered Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA Code which filters a particular Column by WC. What I would like to do is to Sum up the values against that value without having to do the below, I would like to create a loop.

Any advice?

SUM(KH!R[49]C[3]+KH!R[50]C[3]+KH!R[51]C[3])

```
  Sheets("KH").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$62").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Work"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$F$62").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="WC"
    Sheets("TS").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(KH!R[49]C[3]+KH!R[50]C[3]+KH!R[51]C[3])"
    Range("B4").Select
```

Comment: SUMIFS might be useful, or maybe SUBTOTAL...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering the values and then trying to SUM, could you use SUMIFS?

```
=SUMIFS(KH!C3:C62, KH!B3:B62, "Work", KH!D3:D62, "WC")
```

Comment: Not worked for me I'm sorry, says expression I correct. Can I use VBA?

Comment: In VBA you could use this to put the formula in the cell: 

`Sheets("TS").Range("B4").Formula = "=SUMIFS(KH!C3:C62, KH!B3:B62, "Work", KH!D3:D62, "WC")"`